# Replacement for Cameyo app virtualisation

Tags: windows, cloud, virtualization

The Cameyo virtualisation app was retired in 2018 and is no longer available.

One of its key features was to be able to virtualise your own app and deploy it 'in the cloud', and could therefore be run from any browser on a pc with internet access. The user files were typically held on Dropbox.

Is there a direct alternative or something very similar?